# Testing existing Ubuntu scopes without a supported device

Tags: application-development, scopes

I'm interested in participating in the Ubuntu app Showdown in which you have to make a scope.

But before I begin developing I'd like to see how scopes work and what scopes are available.

I don't have a device which Ubuntu officially supports such as a Nexus 4. What other ways are there to take a look at the existing scopes developed? Is there at least a store where all the scopes can be viewed on the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an emulator from Qt Creator to see and explore the existing scopes on a virtual device. Here's a screenshot of how to create one.

1. Go to the **Devices** tab in Qt Creator
2. Click on the "**+**" button on the bottom left hand side to open the Emulator creation dialog
3. Give the emulator a name, select the **devel-proposed** channel and press the **Create** button

[image]

Additionally, here are some screenshots of the default scopes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGsK9.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I've had trouble getting the emulators running most likely because I've messed up my packages while updating to Utopic.
I'll do a fresh install of 14.10 and follow your instructions.

Comment: You can get started writing the scope without the emulator, using the Unity scopes tool. This will get you kickstarted and you can get a working scope without having to mess with the infrastructure. Once you've got that, if you tell us which exact problems you've had with the emulator, someone can probably help you. Also do watch the scopes workshops: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-qBHd6_LXWYSvPX1uyD5ADBMhl41zbcw, as they'll also help you get started.